# pyinstaller in virtual environmets is installed as unknown

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-venv

I'm trying to install pyinstaller in a `venv` using the following instructions:

1. First I create a folder to locate my files
2. in cmd, I run `Python -m venv env` to create a virtual environment
3. I use `call env/Scripts/activate` to start `venv`
4. run `pip install pyinstaller`
5. this result as `unknown=0.0.0 was installed`

Do you know how I can solve this?

Errors:

[image: screenshot of error messages]

Comment: Try: `./env/Scripts/activate` (without the call) then run pip install again

Comment: Try with the `--no-cache-dir` option to `pip install`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by upgrading "pip" using "Python -m pip install --upgrade pip" then I repeated the "pip install pyinstaller" and it works